# ASP .net core (Erro HTTP 500.19 - Internal Server Error)

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, iis, visual-studio-2017

Tenho um web api, que quando executado no iss apresenta erro 500.19 no browser, sou muito novo no assunto, fiz alguma pesquisa este erro pode ser no web.cofing. Se alguém poder me ajudar agradeço!
Segue Código do web.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.webServer>
      <defaultDocument>
        <files>
          <add value="Index.cshtml" />
        </files>
      </defaultDocument>
      <handlers>
        <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
      </handlers>
      <aspNetCore processPath=".\ApiSa.exe" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" />
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Pode ser no `ApplicationHost.config` ou no `Web.config`, basicamente é quando o seu XML esta mal-formado, com tags invalidas, ou valores incorretos. Podendo ser um ou mais elementos com problema dentro do documento, mas também pode ser outras coisas, só olhando o erro completo, ligue o DEBUG (se estiver desligado) e vai apresentar o erro completo na página. Ou olha no proprio visualstudio.

Comment: Já cerifiquei e o Debug não apresenta nenhum erro!

Comment: tem como mandar um print do que aparece no browser?

Answer (score 1):

Após consultar o site de suporte da Microsoft, link abaixo, verifiquei que umas das causas do erro apresentado ocorre porque o arquivo ApplicationHost.config, ou o arquivo Web.config, contém um elemento XML malformado.

https://support.microsoft.com/pt-br/help/942055/http-error-500-19-error-when-you-open-an-iis-7-0-webpage

Analisei o arquivo Web.config, como este é o mesmo utilizado em outro servidor porém em outra versão do Windows, não constatei qualquer erro de configuração.

Identifiquei que o erro apresentado é decorrente da configuração do IIS; ocorre que, por padrão, algumas configurações do IIS vem desabilitadas.

Para alterar referidas configurações, abra o arquivo applicationHost.config, disponível em:

C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\config\applicationHost.config

O valor da chave overrideModeDefault das seções handlers e modules devem ser alteradas de “Deny” para”Allow” :

Após aplicar os ajustes acima, o erro HTTP 500.19 — Internal Server Error foi corrigido.